# IE computability issue with elements widths

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This page is loading differently in IE than Chrome or FF
http://www.s-maof.com/PRO/index.php?fkapp=9

I am not using any conditional CSS except for a small one that has no relevancy

```
<!--[if !IE]>
    .box{border: 0px solid gray;}
<![endif]-->
```

What can this be?

Comment: `I am not using any conditional CSS` <--I think that is why the page is loading differently. In my webs I have different CSS for IE and others browsers.

Comment: @Pabloker, It is not required to have special CSS dedicated to each browser in order for pages to behave consistently... that's what the W3C programming standards are for.

Comment: @Sparky672 I'm sorry. I didn't want to say: "This is the only way". In my case, my application must coexist with IE 7, 8 and 9. I solved this problem using one CSS exclusive for IE. But, insist, I didn't want to say "it is required".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *not required* to have special CSS dedicated to each browser in order for pages to behave consistently... that's what the W3C *programming standards* are for.

Fix [your invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.s-maof.com%2FPRO%2Findex.php%3Ffkapp%3D9&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  You have lots of unclosed and mismatched tags.  IE will not deal with invalid HTML very well.

[http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.s-maof.com/PRO/index.php?fkapp=9&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Also, remove the empty line above `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.  Explorer does **not** like having *anything* above or before the `doctype`.  Otherwise, it slips into Quirks-mode.

Comment: thanks - it works! now I have another problem with the page jquery (only in IE..) but that is another subject